# Multiple column criteria in one row

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a process with 12 steps, and designed a report as such:

> TaskDescription StartDate DueDate CompletedDate TaskOwner MainRef

I grouped this by MainRef so I can see all 12 tasks, one below the other, before printing a gap, then moving onto the next MainRef record. I need to change this such that it shows one row for each MainRef (rather than 12, one for each TaskDescription) and then have the TaskDescription and Dates in each column (i.e. would look more like this):

> MainRef Task1 StartDate DueDate CompletedDate Task2 StartDate DueDate CompletedDate...........

This helps determine whether KPIs were met/identify hold ups and knock on effect to overall project. How can I accomplish this?

I have Crystal Reports 9, 2008 & 2011

Comment: Katy, try presenting this as a question, and then making that question generic instead of using your specific vernacular. Instead of, "I have this, and I need it to be this, can you help?" try "How do I take this, and turn it into this?" I'm not super familiar with crystal reports, but it sounds like you've created a stepped report and your customer wants you to create a matrix report using the same data.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I don't believe that makes my question any less understandable, whilst it may be your preference for me to rephrase it. Advice on the site in asking questions is also clear about being specific as possible, rather than asking generic ones, which is what I have followed.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new CrossTab. Set the row to `MainRef` and the column to `Task`.

Decide on the metrics needed for each task, then add them as the CrossTab values.

Use conditional formatting to highlight cases that deserve attention.